# Problem with missing and unexpected keys while loading my model in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to load the model using this tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#saving-loading-model-for-inference . Unfortunately I'm very beginner and I face some problems.

I have created checkpoint:

```
checkpoint = {'epoch': epochs, 'model_state_dict': model.state_dict(), 'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),'loss': loss}
torch.save(checkpoint, 'checkpoint.pth')
```

Then I wrote class for my network and I wanted to load the file:

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(9216, 4096)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(4096, 1000)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(1000, 102)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = log(F.softmax(x, dim=1))
        return x
```

Like that:

```
def load_checkpoint(filepath):
    checkpoint = torch.load(filepath)
    model = Network()
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
    optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
    epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
    loss = checkpoint['loss']

model = load_checkpoint('checkpoint.pth')
```

I got this error (edited to show whole communicate):

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Network:
    Missing key(s) in state_dict: "fc1.weight", "fc1.bias", "fc2.weight", "fc2.bias", "fc3.weight", "fc3.bias". 
    Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "features.0.weight", "features.0.bias", "features.3.weight", "features.3.bias", "features.6.weight", "features.6.bias", "features.8.weight", "features.8.bias", "features.10.weight", "features.10.bias", "classifier.fc1.weight", "classifier.fc1.bias", "classifier.fc2.weight", "classifier.fc2.bias", "classifier.fc3.weight", "classifier.fc3.bias".
```

This is my `model.state_dict().keys()`:

```
odict_keys(['features.0.weight', 'features.0.bias', 'features.3.weight', 
'features.3.bias', 'features.6.weight', 'features.6.bias', 
'features.8.weight', 'features.8.bias', 'features.10.weight', 
'features.10.bias', 'classifier.fc1.weight', 'classifier.fc1.bias', 
'classifier.fc2.weight', 'classifier.fc2.bias', 'classifier.fc3.weight', 
'classifier.fc3.bias'])
```

This is my model:

```
AlexNet(
  (features): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(11, 11), stride=(4, 4), padding=(2, 2))
    (1): ReLU(inplace)
    (2): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (3): Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2))
    (4): ReLU(inplace)
    (5): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (6): Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (7): ReLU(inplace)
    (8): Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (9): ReLU(inplace)
    (10): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace)
    (12): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)

((classifier): Sequential(
(fc1): Linear(in_features=9216, out_features=4096, bias=True)
(relu1): ReLU()
(fc2): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1000, bias=True)
(relu2): ReLU()
(fc3): Linear(in_features=1000, out_features=102, bias=True)
(output): LogSoftmax()
)
)
```

It's my first network ever and I'm blundering along. Thanks for steering me into right direction!

Comment: What if you just rename the corresponding keys in your `model.state_dict().keys()`, so that `features.3.weight` becomes `fc3.weight`, and so on?

Comment: I'll try and let you know in a moment

Comment: It's weird but when I do it, after loading the model is `None`

Comment: Ah OK, so because you are not using a `return` value on the function, when you call `load_checkpoint` it returns nothing; hence `NoneType`. If you want to return the model from your function, you need to add `return model` to the bottom of your function. If you do not need to return it, remove the `model = ` from the `model = load_checkpoint('checkpoint.pth')` which will just call the function.

Comment: If you want to return multiple variables, you would need to return them individually. E.g. `return checkpoint, model, epoc, loss` etc.. and where you call the function, you will need to catch each return value in to another variable. E.g. `checkpoint, model, epoc, loss = load_checkpoint('checkpoint.pth')`

Comment: Thanks for help Adam. I'm closer and closer. The problem right now is I get only fc1, fc2, fc3 model without AlexNet features so I can't really come back to train it.

Answer (score 9):

So your `Network` is essentially the `classifier` part of `AlexNet` and you're looking to load pretrained `AlexNet` weights into it. The problem is that the keys in `state_dict` are "fully qualified", which means that if you look at your network as a tree of nested modules, a key is just a list of modules in each branch, joined with dots like `grandparent.parent.child`. You want to

1. Keep only the tensors with name starting with "classifier."
2. Remove the "classifier." part of keys

so try

```
model = Network()
loaded_dict = checkpoint['model_state_dict']
prefix = 'classifier.'
n_clip = len(prefix)
adapted_dict = {k[n_clip:]: v for k, v in loaded_dict.items()
                if k.startswith(prefix)}
model.load_state_dict(adapted_dict)
```

Comment: It doesn't return any error but when I `print(model)` it shows `None`. I mean after this `model = load_checkpoint('checkpoint.pth')`

Comment: I tried to achieve 1) and 2) in a more understandable way for me but the outcome is still the same. The model after loading is empty.

Comment: Right, as mentioned by Adam above, you need to return the model if you want to get it as the return value of your function.

Comment: What do you mean? AlexNet is comprised of two parts called `features` and `classifier`. Your `Network` implements only `classifier` so yes, you're losing the `features` part. I was assuming that's what you meant to do

Comment: I'd like to save the whole model to be able to train it in the future

Answer (score 4):

in my case, i had to remove "module." prefix from the state dict to load.

```py
    model= Model()
    state_dict = torch.load(model_path)
    remove_prefix = 'module.'
    state_dict = {k[len(remove_prefix):] if k.startswith(remove_prefix) else k: v for k, v in state_dict.items()}
```

After that,

```py
    model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
```

Worked!